# Unable to get accessory list using showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, external-accessory, eaaccessory

I am developing an iOS application which using external accessory framework to communicate with hardware device.

Problem :

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil
                                                                             completion:nil];
```

Above method always return empty list.
I have seen a lot links and questions but didn't find any solution.

Supported external accessory protocols is already added to info.plist

Could any one have idea about it? It would be appreciate.

Comment: If you connect to it manually in Settings.app, and then `[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]` is still empty?

Comment: I am receiving connected accessory in [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories] but unable to get list in accessory picker.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for those who stumbled across, make sure to:

Add the protocols in your `Info.plist`

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
<array>
    <string>com.protocol.test</string>
    <string>com.apple.p1</string>
</array>
```

And enable "Background Modes" from "Your Project" > "Capabilities" > "Background Modes". Then check "*External accessory communication*".